# run perl command in python file

Tags: python, shell, perl

```
import subprocess
result=subprocess.Popen(['perl','Hello.pl'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
out,err=result.communicate()
print out
```

This is my program , i am trying to run a `perl` program inside a python file . I am using python `2.6v` .

> While running this file it's not giving anything .

I am new to python .

Can anyone help ?

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not giving anything"?

Answer (score 2):

From [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) documentation for `communicate()`:

> Interact with process: Send data to stdin. Read data from stdout and
>   stderr, until end-of-file is reached. **Wait for process to terminate**.

Don't use `shell=True`, if you want to write and read without waiting for the process to stop. Refer this [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) for details.

Use this code:

```
import subprocess
result=subprocess.Popen(['perl','Hello.pl'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out,err=result.communicate()
print out
```

*How can i read some arguments from command line and pass as an input . For Ex : perl Hello.pl some_variable_name*

**You can do that using [argparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html)**

Python code:

```
import subprocess
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Test Python Code')
parser.add_argument('first_name', metavar='FIRST_NAME', type=str,
                    help='Enter the first name')
parser.add_argument('second_name', metavar='SECOND_NAME', type=str,
                    help='Enter the second name')

# Parse command line arguments
args = parser.parse_args()

result=subprocess.Popen(['perl','Hello.pl',args.first_name,args.second_name],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out,err=result.communicate()
print out
```

Perl Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

# (1) quit unless we have the correct number of command-line args
$num_args = $#ARGV + 1;
if ($num_args != 2) {
    print "\nUsage: name.pl first_name last_name\n";
    exit;
}

# (2) we got two command line args, so assume they are the
# first name and last name
$first_name=$ARGV[0];
$last_name=$ARGV[1];

print "First name: $first_name \nSecond name: $last_name\n";
```

Sample output:
[image]

Comment: How can i read some arguments from command line and pass as an input . For Ex : perl Hello.pl <some variable name>

Comment: @Aakashk.u: I've edited the answer to include what you've asked though it's 'out of the scope of the original question' asked. Please 'mark answer as accepted' if it served the purpose or helped you.